# Wix CustomActionData property value is empty when read from inside a Rust custom action 2 out of 10 times

Tags: wix, windows-installer, race-condition, intermittent

In WIX code we declare the deferred custom action that will secure the credentials and the
auxiliary custom action that sets the CustomActionData value for it as follows:

```
    <CustomAction Id="SetUserNamePasswordForDefferedAction" Property="HandleAccountInfoCustomAction" Value="[ACCOUNT_USERNAME],[ACCOUNT_PASSWORD],[INSTALLLOCATION],[SERVICEACCOUNT]" HideTarget="no" Return="check" />
    <CustomAction Id="HandleAccountInfoCustomAction" DllEntry="handle_account_info" BinaryKey="service_account_dll" Execute="deferred" HideTarget="no" Impersonate="no" Return="check"/>
    <Binary Id="service_account_dll" SourceFile="service_account.dll" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="HandleAccountInfoCustomAction" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
        <Custom Action="SetUserNamePasswordForDefferedAction" Before="HandleAccountInfoCustomAction">NOT Installed</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

`service_account_dll` is implemented in Rust but exports the entry point `handle_account_info` in C format. The rust code that reads the custom action data is the following:

```rust
unsafe fn retrieve_property_from_msi_db(
    h_install: MSIHANDLE,
    property_name_str: &str,
) -> StdResult<String, u32> {
    let property_name = get_ptr_to_cstring(property_name_str);
    custom_action_log(&format!("Retrieve {property_name_str} from MSI db"));
    let mut msi_get_property_call_count = 0usize;
    let mut res;
    let mut req_status;
    let mut buff = [0u8; BUFFER_SIZE];

    res = 0u32;
    req_status = 234u32; // ERROR_MORE_DATA

    while (WIN32_ERROR(req_status) == ERROR_MORE_DATA || res == 0) && msi_get_property_call_count < 5 {
        res = buff.len() as u32;
        req_status = MsiGetPropertyA(
            h_install,
            PCSTR::from_raw(property_name),
            PSTR::from_raw(buff.as_mut_ptr()),
            Some(&mut res as *mut u32),
        );
        if msi_get_property_call_count > 0 && WIN32_ERROR(req_status) == ERROR_MORE_DATA {
            // Register the occurrence of a known race condition in MSI
            custom_action_log(format!("WARN: Multiple calls to MsiGetPropertyA ({msi_get_property_call_count}) returned ERROR_MORE_DATA.").as_str());
        }
        if res == 0 {
            custom_action_log(format!("WARN: MsiGetPropertyA returned 0 bytes for property {property_name_str}.").as_str());
            std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10));
        }

        msi_get_property_call_count += 1;

        if res as usize > BUFFER_SIZE {
            custom_action_log(format!("Custom action buffer size is too small: Needed {res}/available {BUFFER_SIZE}.").as_str());
            return Err(ERROR_INSTALL_FAILED.0);
        }
    }
    if ERROR_SUCCESS != WIN32_ERROR(req_status) {
        custom_action_log(format!("Failed to retrieve user name from MSI:WIN_32ERROR {:?}, req_status: {req_status}", WIN32_ERROR(req_status)).as_str());
        return Err(ERROR_INSTALL_FAILED.0);
    }

    let property = std::str::from_utf8_unchecked(&buff[..res as usize]);

    Ok(property.to_string())
}
```

Two or three out of ten I get the following in the custom action logs:

```
2023-11-14 13:29:47 - Retrieve CustomActionData from MSI db
2023-11-14 13:29:47 - WARN: MsiGetPropertyA returned 0 bytes for property CustomActionData.
2023-11-14 13:29:47 - WARN: MsiGetPropertyA returned 0 bytes for property CustomActionData.
2023-11-14 13:29:47 - WARN: MsiGetPropertyA returned 0 bytes for property CustomActionData.
2023-11-14 13:29:47 - WARN: MsiGetPropertyA returned 0 bytes for property CustomActionData.
2023-11-14 13:29:47 - WARN: MsiGetPropertyA returned 0 bytes for property CustomActionData.
2023-11-14 13:29:47 - service_account CustomActionData data retrieved from MSI db.
2023-11-14 13:29:47 - TROUBLESHOOTING: CustomActionData:
2023-11-14 13:29:47 - CustomActionData property is not in the expected format
```

A successful run produces the following logs:

```
2023-11-14 13:28:48 - Retrieve CustomActionData from MSI db
2023-11-14 13:28:48 - service_account CustomActionData data retrieved from MSI db.
2023-11-14 13:28:48 - TROUBLESHOOTING: CustomActionData: ,,C:\MyApp,NT Authority\Local Service
```

Help, please :-)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by changing my strategy. Long story short, instead of a custom action implemented in a DLL to be loaded by the wix installer app, the custom action is a standalone executable now where arguments are passed through the command line. Wix provides support for doing that without logging the command line arguments so the password is not logged. I followed [this documentation article](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/customactions/qtexec/), in particular the *WixSilentExec* flavor.

My understanding as to why directly accessing a dll from Wix turned out to be unstable is that the mechanism to pass argument values going through the *CustomActionData* property in the MSI database is prone to race conditions.

Note: v3 of Wix target is a 32-bit executable, using a custom action dll might also be a source of instability.